# Problem with printer in java

Tags: java, printing, ip, ip-address, printers

I have a problem, what happens is I want to send to print a file at a printer, for which I get the IP address of the printers I have networked and choose the first, here is the code for this:

```
PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();// list of ip address 

PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

printJob.setPrintService(service[0]);//I get the first address
```

But now I want to assign the string that contains the IP address:`\\10.100.20.26\My printer` of the printer that I want, and not the network that I have, and it is there that do not know how , someone please help me, I've searched for the solution, but I have not had good results.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the `PrintService` has some property that give you its path. So go over the array of `PrintService`s to find one that matches the path you have and use it:

```
PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();// list of ip address
String myPrinter = "10.100.20.26\My printer";
PrintService serviceToUse = null;

for (PrintService service: services) {
    if (service.getPath().equals(myPrinter)) {
        serviceToUse = service;
        break;
    }
}

if (serviceToUse != null) {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    printJob.setPrintService(serviceToUse);
}
```

Comment: Mmmm....I want to add a new ip address, not from the list services, because I have a String myPrinter = "10.100.20.26\My printer";  but I don't know how to print to that ip address

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void printFile(File file, String printerIp) throws PrintException, IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket(printerIp, 9100);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];

        fileInputStream.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

             //Curious thing is that we have to wait some time to make more prints.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        socket.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
    }

    //void main
      File f = new File("C:\\Users\\SHINWAR\\Desktop\\link.txt");
    try {
        printFile(f, "192.168.1.100"); //f : file to print , ip printer
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e + "--file");
    }
```

print from ip and send file .txt